# Why is ucontext_t so much larger than sigjmp_buf?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, signals, glibc

On x86_64 Linux, with:

```
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    #define PRSZ(X) printf("sizeof(" #X ")=%zu\n", sizeof(X))
    PRSZ(ucontext_t); //contains mcontext_t, stack_t, sigset_t, and on glibc this struct _libc_fpstate
    PRSZ(mcontext_t);
    PRSZ(stack_t);
    PRSZ(sigset_t);
    //PRSZ(struct _libc_fpstate); //512
    PRSZ(sigjmp_buf);  //contains sigset_t
}
```

I get:

```
sizeof(ucontext_t)=936 
sizeof(mcontext_t)=256
sizeof(stack_t)=24
sizeof(sigset_t)=128
sizeof(sigjmp_buf)=200
```

Why is `ucontext_t` so much larger than `sigjmp_buf` and `mcontext_t` so much larger than `sizeof(sigjmp_buf)-sizeof(sigset_t)`?

I thought (sig)longjmp could be used to restore context from a (sig)jmp_buf just the same as setcontext could be used to restore context form ucontext_t, but much more context is saved and restored in the latter case.

What extra things does `setcontext` do compared to `siglongjmp`?

Comment: `siglongjmp` only need to save those registers that any procedure would have to save before using them.  This is much less than all registers, which is what `setcontext` has to save.

Comment: Following up on @fuz's point, remember that in x86-64 System V, all the vector registers are call-clobbered.  YMM0..15 are a total of 512 bytes (`32B * 16`), while ZMM0..31 would be `64B * 32` = 2048 plus 8x 8 bytes for mask regs.   About half of the 16x 8-byte GP integer regs are call-preserved so setjmp omits about 64 bytes of integer regs.  (Because it looks like a plain function call to compiler-generated code, thus the compiler will assume the call-clobbered registers are clobbered.)

Comment: Thank you fuz and Peter Cordes. Now I understand why sigaction handlers use ucontext_t rather than just a sigjmp_buf. I'll leave the question in case somebody wishes to asnwer with greater detail.

Comment: This makes me wonder why people ever wanted to use the ucontext_t and family for context switching. Seems to me like there's only one legitimate user of that and that is the OS when setting up signal handler frames (because only there is register usage truly unpredictable due to the asynchrony of the interruption). Everywhere else (sig)setjmp/(sig)longjmp must be sufficient.